# How to disable *sources.jar download during Sync in Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, multi-module

IDE keeps sending *-sources.jar requests on each sync. This files are missing on server, so it leads to waste of time on each sync (especially on multi module projects). Is there a gradle or IDE option to disable this file requests? or optimize number of requests for multi module project?

[image: Requests in Wireshark]

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions how to build project offline:

1. - Do it in terminal

`gradle --offline build`

2. - Change it in gradle window (Android Studio 3.6.1)

[image]